# SQL Server cannot find special characters

Tags: sql-server

My table has records like this one

```
◦  bla bla bla bla
```

and other records like this one

```
◾ bla bla bla bla
```

When I try this query I get zero records

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Rec LIKE '◦%'
```

How can I make SQL Server read this char?

Edit :

SQL Server 2019 (v15)

Comment: What collation are you using? What version of SQL Server are you using? How have you configured your client's encoding and connection-collation?

Comment: It is possible that it is an Unicode character, could you try WHERE Rec LIKE N'◦%'

Comment: @Piotr You are right, I works after adding N thanks. put it as an answer so I mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably an Unicode character, you should use `WHERE Rec LIKE N'◦%'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT name, description FROM fn_helpcollations();` to identify the COLLATIONs available to your on your server install and pick one that does NOT have `accent-insensitive` in the description (such as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`).

Then adjust your query accordingly ...

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Rec LIKE '◦%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Various codepages will treat the characters differently and some may even interpret them as different characters completely. Choose wisely.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but did not work. Piotr's solutions worked for me